# Spacing Between Two Labels Using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two labels in the footer of my mobile website. Sometimes the title of the selected product is large and it comes very close to the price as shown below:

[image]

THE HTML:

```
<div style="margin:5px;">

            <span class="stickyProductctName">This is a really really really rea</span>
            <div class="stickyPrice">$1142.00</div>
        </div>
```

The styles for both the elements are shown below:

```
#stickyFooter .stickyProductctName {
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 85%;
}


#stickyFooter .stickyPrice {
font-weight: bold;
width: 15%;
float: right;
margin-right: 20px;
}
```

How can I improve it? Wrap it!

Comment: In your css, why you use #stickyFooter

Comment: That is the id of the element which the css will be applied to.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is because you have a total width of the elements of `100%` and a `margin-right` of 20px. It is overflowing.

Comment: Can you provide a possible solution with an example?

Comment: If I don't give a margin then the price cuts off from the right hand side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

- put the `margin-right` on the `.stickyProductctName`;
- add `display:inline-block;` to `.stickyPrice`

Comment: The price cuts off the screen if I do not put margin-right on it.

Answer (score 0):

How bout stack them on top of each other for mobile view?

CSS:

```
#stickyFooter .stickyProductctName {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}


#stickyFooter .stickyPrice {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a JSFiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/shannabarnard/Ls75o3cr/

Firstly, you need to put both elements in a span, it doesn't work well semantically to have one as a span and the other as a div contained within another div.

Change your widths, and give the price both a left and right padding.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin:5px;">
    <span class="stickyProductctName">This is a really re ally reall yreally  really re ally really re reall y really really rereally really really re rea</span>
    <span class="stickyPrice">$1142.00</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.stickyProductctName {
text-transform: uppercase;
float: left;
display:inline;
width:85%;
}

.stickyPrice {
font-weight: bold;
width: 10%;
float: right;
margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Shanna, I think the link to JSFiddle is missing.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is that you used margin instead of padding. As long as border-box is being used (It is standard on frameworks), padding eats the inside of containers instead of adding it. All you need to change is:

```
#stickyFooter .stickyPrice {
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 15%;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

In case you don't have border-box on the site, [here is a good article about it](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). Frameworks usually use a rule like this:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```